# Implement Dolby with corona

Tags: coronasdk, dolby, dolby-audio-api

I'm trying to trying implement Dolby in my Amazon build.
I'm using corona SDK, but I didnt find documentation for that, is possible add Dolby in my Corona Project?

Comment: @Jarrod I thought [company name tags were bad](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190914/135887)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately, there is no Corona Solution just yet! Make sure to reach out to Corona Lab and let them know you want this.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, is true. I sent an email to chartboost support center and they are developing a solution for corona, but, not is done yet.